# how to play audio media directly in my windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player, media

I am making a ringtone setter application for windows phone 7. Can i ask a function so that the user can play the chosen ringtone in my application itself without exiting it. Or do i have to launch the media player.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use BackgroundAudioPlayer to achieve this. There is some explanation [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
I hope it helps!